# kubernetes: ELB not redirecting to https despite nginx configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, kubernetes

I have a `LoadBalancer` service on a `k8s` deployment on `aws` (made via `kops`).

Service definition is as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ui
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: <certificate_id>
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "443"
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: ui-port
    protocol: TCP
  - name: https
    port: 443
    targetPort: ui-port
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    els-pod: ui
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Here is the respective deployment:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ui-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        els-pod: ui
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: <my_ecr_registry>/<my_image>:latest
        name: ui
        ports:
        - name: ui-port
          containerPort: 80
      restartPolicy: Always
```

I know that `<my_image>` exposes port `80`.

I have also assigned an alias to the `ELB` that gets deployed, say. `my-k8s.mydomain.org`

The `ui` pods include an `nginx` image, which within **both** within the `server` context and the `/` location block, has the following directive:

```
  if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }
```

However when accessing the service (i.e. the domain name assigned as an alias to the `ELB`) via `http`, I do not get redirected to `https`.

Comment: Please, share your full nginx configuration

Answer (score 0):

I had the opposite problem and solved it by adding a nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false".

Maybe for you a config like:

```
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
```

could fix your problem?